# concatenate strings with backslash in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, backslash

When passing the input

```
A = 'hello'
B = 'by'
sum = A + '\\' + B
```

I get

```
'hello\\bye'
```

I WOULD like to get

```
'hello\bye'
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: Try doing `print sum` and see what you get.  I'm guessing you are using the interpreter to look at the value of `sum`, which will show you the quotes and the escaped backslash.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But the OP explicitly said they did *not* want that...